# Building libical-1.0 on OS X fails

Tags: c, build, compilation, makefile, libical

I'm trying to use libical for a C-project. Unfortunately, the `make` command gives me the following output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in design-data
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in doc
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in scripts
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in test-data
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in src
Making all in libical
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../src -I../../src -I../../src/libical -I../../src/libical -I. -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/libical/share/libical"\"   -g -O2 -MT icalderivedparameter.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/icalderivedparameter.Tpo -c -o icalderivedparameter.lo icalderivedparameter.c
mv -f .deps/icalderivedparameter.Tpo .deps/icalderivedparameter.Plo
mv: rename .deps/icalderivedparameter.Tpo to .deps/icalderivedparameter.Plo: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [icalderivedparameter.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm not sure whats wrong here. I'm running OS X 10.9 and gcc.

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call `./bootstrap`.

```
./bootstrap
./configure
make
make install
```

Bootstrap was the key for me.